# passwordToggleEnabled set to true but not working

Tags: android, xml, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I'm looking to use passwordToggleEnabled with TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText. The problem I'm having is that the icon appears but when clicking it, nothing happens. It almost seems like clicking it just refocuses on the TextInputEditText rather than unmasking the password. I'm thinking this because the pointer under the cursor will very quickly pulse lighter then back to default color as if I'm clicking within the focused EditText.

I'm using a custom background for the TextInputEditText to have white, circular bubbles when inputting information, but I realized the white background in my custom drawable was covering the icon. So when the field is focused, the bubble now has a stroke and a transparent background so the icon is visible.

I've tried completely removing the background but the icon still didn't do anything.

Here's the custom background (rounded_edit_text.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="false">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:top="@dimen/_3sdp">
                <shape
                    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
                    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
                    <corners
                        android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
                        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
                        android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
                        android:topRightRadius="30dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>

        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:top="@dimen/_3sdp">
                <shape
                    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
                    <solid android:color="@color/Transparent"/>
                    <corners
                        android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
                        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
                        android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
                        android:topRightRadius="30dp"/>
                    <stroke
                        android:color="@color/evenlightergrey"
                        android:width="@dimen/_1sdp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>

        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And here is the password bit of the layout:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password_textInput"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/email_bottom_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/start_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/end_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/password_bottom_guideline"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/PurpleFloatingHintStyle"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/main_purple">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password_editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_32sdp"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/main_purple_cursor"
            android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:inputType="textPassword"

            android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:hint="Password"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/start_guideline"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/end_guideline"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And some screenshots to round things out:

[image: Full Layout]

[image: Password focused]

Is there something I'm missing? I've watched some YouTube videos that seem to do it the same way as I have here, and an older version of this code also has a lot of the same stuff and it's working. Thank you!

Comment: Remove the background on the EditText. The TextInputLayout  set the proper background on it.

Comment: I've tried moving the background to the TextInputLayout instead of the EditText and that also didn't work. I also tried removing backgrounds entirely, that didn't work either.

Comment: Which version of material components are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"` in your `TextInputEditText`

With elevation

[image]

Without elevation

[image]

It is not related to your issue but use:

```
  app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
  app:endIconTint="@color/..."
```

instead of:

```
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/main_purple"
```

Comment: This seems to have worked. I use was using elevation to get that nice looking drop shadow effect but it seems to be at the price of the icon. Then when I apply the background to the TextInputLayout in order to have both, it stretches it out in a funky way and the floating hint is half in the box and half out. I'll mess around with it. Thank you so much for taking the time.

Comment: @daniel-eh the icon and the EditText are added in a FrameLayout. Using an elevation the EditText covers the icon.