app:passwordToggleEnabled not working, no funciona
I am working on a login for my application, but I implemented an app:passwordToggleEnabled, but it is not visible, I even added an app:passwordToggleTint but it is still not visible, I hope you can guide me because I can't find anything about this and I am new to this language
estoy trabajando en un login para mi aplicacion, pero implemente un app:passwordToggleEnabled, pero no es visible, incluso añadi un app:passwordToggleTint pero siguie sin ser visible, espero y me puedan orientar porque no encuentro nada sobre esto y soy nuevo en este lenguaje
Este es el código XML
This is the XML code
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/blue"
        style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:hint="@string/contrase_a"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


Despite this code, the app:passwordToggleEnabled is not visible
A pesar de este codigo, el app:passwordToggleEnabled no es visible
Here are my gradle imports:
Aquí están mis importaciones de Gradle:
    implementación(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.1"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth: 22.1.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0")
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1")
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.firebase.auth.ktx)

styles.xml
<style name="GFSTextInputLayoutTheme" parent="Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/light_grey</item>
        <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/light_grey</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/light_grey</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/light_blue</item>
    </style>


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62821194/passwordtoggleenabled-set-to-true-but-not-working

I already checked that and no, it didn't help me either
